# Coroutine cancellation in room database operations

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, cancellation

I have a screen with a corresponding `ViewModel`. This screen is a form to be filled and then recorded in a `Room` database.

After each insertion, some other tables have to be updated accordingly as well.

I have this function in my repository:

```kotlin
 suspend fun writeTransactionToDatabase(transaction: Transaction) {
        db.withTransaction { // <-- "magic" solution
            transactionDao.insert(transaction)
            updateCategoryAndValue(transaction)
            updateBalance(transaction)
        }
    }
```

where `updateCategoryAndValue` and `updateBalance` are both `suspend` functions.
I call this function from my viewmodel and immediately navigate away. It is my understanding that this means the viewmodel is destroyed.
And since I called this method like so:

```kotlin
 viewModelScope.launch {
     repository.writeTransactionToDatabase(transaction)
 }
```

I am assuming this means that function is canelled when the viewmodel is destroyed. However by adding `withTransaction` somehow the bug appears to be fixed.

I want to know how does this cancellation work in this case, does room continue the current transaction if it has started and `withTransaction` makes it atomic so somehow it now finishes?

I have ran this in a debugger, and without it, the function appears to be cancelled halfway through the body of the third called function, namely `updateBalance()`. And when I added the `withTransaction`, the UI is not shown and the function seems to continue until termination.

Can someone explain what is going on here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the UI is not shown and the function seems to continue until termination." - what does it mean that it is not shown? Is it shown blank? Does it wait for the operation to finish and only then show up?

Comment: yes the UI appears frozen. I will have to investigate further though using a delay or similar to investigate whether using withTransaction blocked the UI thread or something similar. It was 3 AM I didn't investigate this further as it was bedsides the point. See the accepted answer for further details about the main question issue.

Comment: @broot just added a `delay` to the `withTransaction` block and it does not block the main thread, no issue with that, it seems. Now removed the mention of UI in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to the answer by @MikeT, I think the root cause of this behavior is located in the `RoomDatabase.startTransactionCoroutine()`:

```kotlin
suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    try {
        transactionExecutor.execute {
            try {
                ...
            } catch (ex: Throwable) {
                // If anything goes wrong, propagate exception to the calling coroutine.
                continuation.cancel(ex)
            }
        }
    } catch (ex: RejectedExecutionException) {
        // Couldn't acquire a thread, cancel coroutine.
        continuation.cancel(
            IllegalStateException(
                "Unable to acquire a thread to perform the database transaction.", ex
            )
        )
    }
}
```

This code fragment looks strange to me. They schedule the execution on top of their own executor. They properly pass failures from the executor to coroutine, but they don't do the other way around - they ignore coroutine cancellations.

During regular execution, it properly waits for the operation to finish and only then return from the suspend function. But in the case of a cancellation, function returns immediately, while the operation is still running in the background. So cancellation doesn't cancel the operation, it only detaches waiting for it.

I don't know if this is intentional or some kind of a bug, but at least for me this behavior is very confusing. First, cancellation doesn't cancel. Second, behavior is inconsistent: sometimes it waits for the operation to finish and sometimes it runs it in the background.

Comment: _cancellation doesn't cancel the operation, it only detaches waiting for it_ This aligns well with what I have suspected. Thanks for the effort looking into the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Each database access is a single transaction, unless otherwise specified. So without `withTransaction` each access is a single transaction.

Perhaps refer to **RoomDatabase.Ext** (**2.5.2** in this case) which allows you to see exactly what is happening :-

```
/*
 * Copyright 2019 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
@file:JvmName("RoomDatabaseKt")

package androidx.room

import androidx.annotation.RestrictTo
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
import kotlin.coroutines.ContinuationInterceptor
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext
import kotlin.coroutines.coroutineContext
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.asContextElement
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.suspendCancellableCoroutine
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

/**
 * Calls the specified suspending [block] in a database transaction. The transaction will be
 * marked as successful unless an exception is thrown in the suspending [block] or the coroutine
 * is cancelled.
 *
 * Room will only perform at most one transaction at a time, additional transactions are queued
 * and executed on a first come, first serve order.
 *
 * Performing blocking database operations is not permitted in a coroutine scope other than the
 * one received by the suspending block. It is recommended that all [Dao] function invoked within
 * the [block] be suspending functions.
 *
 * The internal dispatcher used to execute the given [block] will block an utilize a thread from
 * Room's transaction executor until the [block] is complete.
 */
public suspend fun <R> RoomDatabase.withTransaction(block: suspend () -> R): R {
    val transactionBlock: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> R = transaction@{
        val transactionElement = coroutineContext[TransactionElement]!!
        transactionElement.acquire()
        try {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            beginTransaction()
            try {
                val result = block.invoke()
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                setTransactionSuccessful()
                return@transaction result
            } finally {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                endTransaction()
            }
        } finally {
            transactionElement.release()
        }
    }
    // Use inherited transaction context if available, this allows nested suspending transactions.
    val transactionDispatcher = coroutineContext[TransactionElement]?.transactionDispatcher
    return if (transactionDispatcher != null) {
        withContext(transactionDispatcher, transactionBlock)
    } else {
        startTransactionCoroutine(coroutineContext, transactionBlock)
    }
}

/**
 * Suspend caller coroutine and start the transaction coroutine in a thread from the
 * [RoomDatabase.transactionExecutor], resuming the caller coroutine with the result once done.
 * The [context] will be a parent of the started coroutine to propagating cancellation and release
 * the thread when cancelled.
 */
private suspend fun <R> RoomDatabase.startTransactionCoroutine(
    context: CoroutineContext,
    transactionBlock: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> R
): R = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    try {
        transactionExecutor.execute {
            try {
                // Thread acquired, start the transaction coroutine using the parent context.
                // The started coroutine will have an event loop dispatcher that we'll use for the
                // transaction context.
                runBlocking(context.minusKey(ContinuationInterceptor)) {
                    val dispatcher = coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor]!!
                    val transactionContext = createTransactionContext(dispatcher)
                    continuation.resume(
                        withContext(transactionContext, transactionBlock)
                    )
                }
            } catch (ex: Throwable) {
                // If anything goes wrong, propagate exception to the calling coroutine.
                continuation.cancel(ex)
            }
        }
    } catch (ex: RejectedExecutionException) {
        // Couldn't acquire a thread, cancel coroutine.
        continuation.cancel(
            IllegalStateException(
                "Unable to acquire a thread to perform the database transaction.", ex
            )
        )
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a [CoroutineContext] for performing database operations within a coroutine transaction.
 *
 * The context is a combination of a dispatcher, a [TransactionElement] and a thread local element.
 *
 * * The dispatcher will dispatch coroutines to a single thread that is taken over from the Room
 * transaction executor. If the coroutine context is switched, suspending DAO functions will be able
 * to dispatch to the transaction thread. In reality the dispatcher is the event loop of a
 * [runBlocking] started on the dedicated thread.
 *
 * * The [TransactionElement] serves as an indicator for inherited context, meaning, if there is a
 * switch of context, suspending DAO methods will be able to use the indicator to dispatch the
 * database operation to the transaction thread.
 *
 * * The thread local element serves as a second indicator and marks threads that are used to
 * execute coroutines within the coroutine transaction, more specifically it allows us to identify
 * if a blocking DAO method is invoked within the transaction coroutine. Never assign meaning to
 * this value, for now all we care is if its present or not.
 */
private fun RoomDatabase.createTransactionContext(
    dispatcher: ContinuationInterceptor
): CoroutineContext {
    val transactionElement = TransactionElement(dispatcher)
    val threadLocalElement =
        suspendingTransactionId.asContextElement(System.identityHashCode(transactionElement))
    return dispatcher + transactionElement + threadLocalElement
}

/**
 * A [CoroutineContext.Element] that indicates there is an on-going database transaction.
 *
 * @hide
 */
@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)
internal class TransactionElement(
    internal val transactionDispatcher: ContinuationInterceptor
) : CoroutineContext.Element {

    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<TransactionElement>

    override val key: CoroutineContext.Key<TransactionElement>
        get() = TransactionElement

    /**
     * Number of transactions (including nested ones) started with this element.
     * Call [acquire] to increase the count and [release] to decrease it.
     */
    private val referenceCount = AtomicInteger(0)

    fun acquire() {
        referenceCount.incrementAndGet()
    }

    fun release() {
        val count = referenceCount.decrementAndGet()
        if (count < 0) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Transaction was never started or was already released.")
        }
    }
}
```